# xs:anyAttributes is rejecting an attribute

Tags: xsd

In my schema I have:

```
<xs:element name="html-script">
    <xs:annotation>
       <xs:documentation>Element used to specify pass-through Javascript</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
         <xs:anyAttribute/>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In a document I have:

```
<html-attributes target="_new"/>
```

When I validate, I get ...

> Validation error: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'target' is not allowed to appear in element 'html-attributes'. at file:/Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/./content/about-us/about-us.xml line 35 character 38

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible Typo? Your schema defines the element `<html-script>` whereas your document uses `<html-attributes>`.

Also try adding the `processContents` directive to your anyAttribute:

```
<xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
```

or

```
<xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax" />
```

Comment: Got the same problem and adding `processContents="skip"` worked for me.